# Hbase daemon crashes at start

Tags: macos, hbase

I am trying to run Hbase 0.96.1.1 for Hadoop 2 on a Mac book air. When I run ./start-hbase.sh,

starting master, logging to.....

but it crashes right after.

```
I checked the log file and this the error message it spat out:

    Fri Mar 28 12:49:20 PDT 2014 Starting master on ms12
    core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
    data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
    file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
    max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
    max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
    open files                      (-n) 256
    pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
    stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
    cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
    max user processes              (-u) 709
    virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,203 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: HBase 0.96.1.1-hadoop2
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,203 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: Subversion file:///home/jon/proj/hbase-svn/hbase-0.96.1.1 -r Unknown
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,204 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: Compiled by jon on Tue Dec 17 12:22:12 PST 2013
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,894 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,894 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:host.name=guest-wireless-nup-nat-206-117-89-004.usc.edu
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,895 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.version=1.6.0_65
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,895 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.vendor=Apple Inc.
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,895 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.home=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,895 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.class.path=/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/conf:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/asm-3.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-codec-1.7.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-math-2.2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/gmbal-api-only-3.0.0-b023.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/grizzly-framework-2.1.2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/grizzly-http-2.1.2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/grizzly-http-server-2.1.2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/grizzly-http-servlet-2.1.2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/grizzly-rcm-2.1.2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-client-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0-tests.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0-tests.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-yarn-client-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-client-0.96.1.1-hadoop2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-common-0.96.1.1-hadoop2-tests.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-common-0.96.1.1-hadoop2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-examples-0.96.1.1-hadoop2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-hadoop-compat-0.96.1.1-hadoop2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-0.96.1.1-hadoop2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-it-0.96.1.1-hadoop2-tests.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-it-0.96.1.1-hadoop2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-prefix-tree-0.96.1.1-hadoop2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-protocol-0.96.1.1-hadoop2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-server-0.96.1.1-hadoop2-tests.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-server-0.96.1.1-hadoop2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-shell-0.96.1.1-hadoop2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-testing-util-0.96.1.1-hadoop2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/hbase-thrift-0.96.1.1-hadoop2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/htrace-core-2.01.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/httpclient-4.1.3.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/httpcore-4.1.3.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/javax.servlet-3.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jersey-grizzly2-1.9.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jersey-test-framework-core-1.9.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jersey-test-framework-grizzly2-1.9.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jettison-1.3.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/libthrift-0.9.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/metrics-core-2.1.2.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,897 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.library.path=.:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,898 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/ww/vvdhqz_d2ggcht76g3fp2zh00000gn/T/
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,898 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,898 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:os.name=Mac OS X
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,898 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:os.arch=x86_64
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,898 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:os.version=10.9.2
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,898 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:user.name=ms12
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,898 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:user.home=/Users/ms12
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,898 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:user.dir=/Users/hbase/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/bin
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,921 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Created server with tickTime 2000 minSessionTimeout 4000 maxSessionTimeout 40000 datadir /Users/hbase/zookeeper-storage-2/zookeeper_0/version-2 snapdir /Users/hbase/zookeeper-storage-2/zookeeper_0/version-2
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,962 INFO  [main] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
    2014-03-28 12:49:21,972 INFO  [main] persistence.FileTxnSnapLog: Snapshotting: 0x0 to /Users/hbase/zookeeper-storage-2/zookeeper_0/version-2/snapshot.0
    2014-03-28 12:49:22,269 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:53624
    2014-03-28 12:49:22,278 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: Processing stat command from /127.0.0.1:53624
    2014-03-28 12:49:22,283 INFO  [Thread-3] server.NIOServerCnxn: Stat command output
    2014-03-28 12:49:22,284 INFO  [Thread-3] server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:53624 (no session established for client)
    2014-03-28 12:49:22,287 INFO  [main] zookeeper.MiniZooKeeperCluster: Started MiniZK Cluster and connect 1 ZK server on client port: 2181
    2014-03-28 12:49:22,328 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClusterUtil.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.addMaster(LocalHBaseCluster.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.<init>(LocalHBaseCluster.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2779)
    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: No such interface $iface
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.getIPs(DNS.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.getIPs(DNS.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.getHosts(DNS.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.getDefaultHost(DNS.java:344)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.getDefaultHost(DNS.java:362)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.getDefaultHost(DNS.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.<init>(HMasterCommandLine.java:256)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClusterUtil.java:137)
        ... 7 more
```

It seems that iface is an network interface on Linux system. Does that mean this version can not be run on Mac?

---

Edited: 
I tested hbase version 0.98 also. Same issue. The only version that is working is hbase 0.94 but it is not compatible with hadoop 2.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you used the instructions here:

http://opentsdb.net/setup-hbase.html

But did not do them correctly.  The string $iface should not actually show up in your hbase-site.xml.  It is expanded to the value of your loopback interface device when you write out your config using the exact commands given in those instructions.  If you just copy-paste the config from there it won't work.  On a mac it should result in lo0 for each of the below properties...

```
 <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.dns.interface</name>
    <value>lo0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.dns.interface</name>
    <value>lo0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.master.dns.interface</name>
    <value>lo0</value>
  </property>
```

Comment: Some instructions online don't include these properties explicitly in the `hbase-site.xml` file example (my case).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue running HBase 98.6-hadoop2 on Ubuntu 12.04. It seems that something changed in the configuration needed for a standalone run mode. Try this in your hbase-site.xml configuration file

```html
<configuration>
  
    <property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>file:///{your hbase data directory}</value>
    </property>
  
    <property>
  <name>hbase.zookeper.property.dataDir</name>
  <value>file:///{your zookeper stuff directory}</value>
    </property>
  
     <property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.dns.interface</name>
  <value>default</value>
    </property>
  
    <property>
  <name>hbase.master.dns.interface</name>
  <value>default</value>
    </property>
  
</configuration>
```

Maybe these links can be of some help

1. http://hbase.apache.org/book/config.files.html#hbase_default_configurations
2. http://www.sujee.net/tech/articles/hadoop/hadoop-dns/